# How to speed up admin-ajax.php in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have Some code on functions.php that i call via ajax on frontend, i'm using admin-ajax which takes about 2-2.5 seconds to load since i have many plugins and that ajax handler need to load all wp core and plugins data, I was wondering how to write a custom ajax handler that only load what is required only to run my snippet below, the brief of my code is that it get woocommerce custom fields via get meta data and read HTTP header for geolocation purpose and implement some variables that i defined to create a button with a link.

```
function simple_amz_link_ajax() {   
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=get_amz_btn'); ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                        action: 'get_simple_amz_button',
                        postId: <?php echo get_post()->ID; ?>
                },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(response) {
                jQuery("#buy_amz_btn_wrap").html(response);

                }

            }); 
        });
    </script> 
    <!-- end Ajax call to get_simple_amz_button -->

    <div id="buy_amz_btn_wrap">

    <div class="spinner">

      <div class="bounce1"></div>
      <div class="bounce2"></div>
      <div class="bounce3"></div>
    </div>

        </div>
    <?php
}



add_action('wp_ajax_get_simple_amz_button', 'simple_amz_button');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_simple_amz_button', 'simple_amz_button');

function simple_amz_button() {  
// Variables Declaration
    $postId = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'postId', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
    $de_asin = get_post_meta( $postId, "wccaf_de_asin", true );

    $country_code = $_SERVER ["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];
    $not_avilable_country = '<div id="amz_not_avilable" class="amz_not_avilable">This product is not avilable in your country yet</div>';

    // Get Amazon Button Title  
    if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == "de") {
        $amz_btn_title = 'Kaufen auf Amazon'; 
        $not_avilable_country = '<div id="amz_not_avilable" class="amz_not_avilable">Dieses Produkt ist in Ihrem Land noch nicht verfügbar</div>';
    }
    if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == "en")  {
        $amz_btn_title = 'Buy on Amazon'; 
        $not_avilable_country = '<div id="amz_not_avilable" class="amz_not_avilable">This product is not avilable in your country yet</div>';
    }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Geolocation Condition
    if ($country_code=="DE" or $country_code=="DE" or $country_code=="AT" or $country_code=="CH" or $country_code=="LI" or $country_code=="EG") {
        $associate_id = "bonstato-21";
        $access_key = "HDUHWUIDIUWJDWDWDWD";
        $secret_key = "HDUIWQDUQWUDJUIQJWDJWQD";
        $amazon_domain = "amazon.de";
        $asin = $de_asin;
    }



    /**********************************************************************************/

    // Get price from amazon

    $amazon = new AmazonAPI($associate_id , $access_key, $secret_key , $amazon_domain);
    $item = $amazon->item_lookup($asin)->get_item_data();
    if ($item->price != "0" && $item->price != null ) {
    ?><div class="amz_price_wrap_wrap" >Price: <?php echo $item->price; ?></div><?php
    }

    global $post;
    $product = wc_get_product( $postId );
    $type = $product->get_type();
    if( $type == 'simple' && $item->price != "0"  && $item->price != null ){    
        if( wp_is_mobile() ) {
            // Amazon Link For Mobile       
            ?>
            <div class="buy_amz_btn_wrap" >     
            <button type="button" id="buy_amz_btn" class="buy_amz_btn" onclick="window.location='https://<?php echo $amazon_domain ?>/dp/<?php echo $asin ?>/?tag=<?php echo $associate_id ?>';"><i class="fa fa-amazon fa-amz"></i><?php echo $amz_btn_title ?></button>                        
            </div>
            <?php
        }

        else {
            // Amazon Link For PC
            ?>
             <div class="buy_amz_btn_wrap" >    
            <button type="button" id="buy_amz_btn" class="buy_amz_btn" onclick="window.location='https://<?php echo $amazon_domain ?>/gp/aws/cart/add.html?AssociateTag=<?php echo $associate_id ?>&ASIN.1=<?php echo $asin ?>&Quantity.1=1';"><i class="fa fa-amazon fa-amz"></i><?php echo $amz_btn_title ?></button>                          
            </div>
            <?php 
        }
    }

    else if( $type == 'simple' && $item->price == "0"){  
        echo $not_avilable_country;
    }


    if(is_null($item->price)){   
        echo $not_avilable_country;
    }





die(); 

}
```

Comment: Hold on, admin-ajax.php does not load any plugin data, it just fires an action from the request if the action exists. You need to identify what exactly takes that long, first I would check the item look up on amazon API.

Comment: actually, I even tried with a simple code like echo "Hello World"; and still takes almost the same time, I disabled plugins and the ajax speed improved for every plugin I disable so it's not an issue of a specific enabled plugin, all plugins are affecting the speed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you still need to use core and WooCommerce functions on your Ajax action. So, basically what you would be doing is use a separate action that doesn't take into consideration the other actions hooked to `wp_ajax_*`. Not sure if this would save you time, but you can try:

```
<?php
function simple_amz_link_ajax() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery( document ).on( 'ready', function () {
            jQuery.ajax( {
                url: "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '?amz=get_amz_btn' ) ); ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    postId: <?php echo absint( get_the_ID() ); ?>,
                    nonce: <?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'get_amz_btn' ); ?>,
                },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function( response ) {
                    jQuery( '#buy_amz_btn_wrap' ).html( response );
                }
            } ); 
        } );
    </script> 
    <!-- end Ajax call to get_simple_amz_button -->

    <div id="buy_amz_btn_wrap">
        <div class="spinner">
            <div class="bounce1"></div>
            <div class="bounce2"></div>
            <div class="bounce3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'simple_amz_link_ajax' );

function simple_amz_button() {
    if ( check_ajax_referer( 'get_amz_btn', 'nonce', false ) && isset( $_GET['amz'] ) && 'get_amz_btn' === $_GET['amz'] ) {
        // Variables Declaration.
        $postId  = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'postId', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
        $de_asin = get_post_meta( $postId, 'wccaf_de_asin', true );

        $country_code         = $_SERVER ['HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY'];
        $not_avilable_country = '<div id="amz_not_avilable" class="amz_not_avilable">This product is not avilable in your country yet</div>';

        // Get Amazon Button Title.
        if ( 'de' === ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE ) {
            $amz_btn_title        = 'Kaufen auf Amazon'; 
            $not_avilable_country = '<div id="amz_not_avilable" class="amz_not_avilable">Dieses Produkt ist in Ihrem Land noch nicht verfügbar</div>';
        } elseif ( 'en' === ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE )  {
            $amz_btn_title        = 'Buy on Amazon'; 
            $not_avilable_country = '<div id="amz_not_avilable" class="amz_not_avilable">This product is not avilable in your country yet</div>';
        }

        // Geolocation Condition.
        if ( 'DE' === $country_code || 'AT' === $country_code || 'CH' === $country_code || 'LI' === $country_code || 'EG' === ) {
            $associate_id  = 'bonstato-21';
            $access_key    = 'HDUHWUIDIUWJDWDWDWD';
            $secret_key    = 'HDUIWQDUQWUDJUIQJWDJWQD';
            $amazon_domain = 'amazon.de';
            $asin          = $de_asin;
        }

        // Get price from amazon
        $amazon = new AmazonAPI( $associate_id , $access_key, $secret_key , $amazon_domain );
        $item   = $amazon->item_lookup( $asin )->get_item_data();

        if ( 0 != $item->price && null != $item->price ) {
            ?>
            <div class="amz_price_wrap_wrap" >Price: <?php echo $item->price; ?></div>
            <?php
        }

        global $post;

        $product = wc_get_product( $postId );
        $type    = $product->get_type();

        if ( 'simple' === $type && 0 != $item->price && null != $item->price ) {    
            if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
                // Amazon Link For Mobile       
                ?>
                <div class="buy_amz_btn_wrap" >     
                    <button type="button" id="buy_amz_btn" class="buy_amz_btn" onclick="window.location='https://<?php echo $amazon_domain ?>/dp/<?php echo $asin ?>/?tag=<?php echo $associate_id ?>';"><i class="fa fa-amazon fa-amz"></i><?php echo $amz_btn_title ?></button>                        
                </div>
                <?php
            } else {
                // Amazon Link For PC
                ?>
                <div class="buy_amz_btn_wrap" >    
                    <button type="button" id="buy_amz_btn" class="buy_amz_btn" onclick="window.location='https://<?php echo $amazon_domain ?>/gp/aws/cart/add.html?AssociateTag=<?php echo $associate_id ?>&ASIN.1=<?php echo $asin ?>&Quantity.1=1';"><i class="fa fa-amazon fa-amz"></i><?php echo $amz_btn_title ?></button>                          
                </div>
                <?php 
            }
        } elseif( 'simple' === $type && 0 == $item->price ) {  
            echo $not_avilable_country;
        }

        if ( is_null( $item->price ) ) {   
            echo $not_avilable_country;
        }

        die(); 
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'simple_amz_button' );
```

**Disclaimer:** This code has not been tested!

What you are doing here is to set up an endpoint that runs the action you want for your Ajax just like another page, but instead of using a pretty permalink, you'd be using a custom query parameter `amz` (practically a separate `wp-ajax.php`). That's why we are using the `template_redirect` hook to check if our custom query parameter is defined and has a value and if so, stop rendering anything else but our Ajax action.

I also added the nonce because **you should always use protection** ;)